# Remove UILabel padding/margin while using auto layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, interface-builder, autolayout

I have a UITableView that uses auto layout.  I have multiple types of cells, but for now let's use the simplest of all, one that only has a UILabel.

In `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` I have the following code:

```
    [self configureCell:self.detailsCell forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self.detailsCell layoutIfNeeded];

    CGSize size = [self.detailsCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
    return size.height + 1;
```

which in turn calls

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // ...
    cell.detailsLabel.text = self.data.myText;
    cell.detailsLabel.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];
    // [cell.detailsLabel sizeToFit]; <- I tried this, but didn't help
}
```

[image: Interface builder screenshot]

and I end up getting this:

[image: Actual cell]

The green rectangle is the actual cell.  The purple rectangle is the UILabel.  I don't want the top and bottom **purple** padding/margin.  How can I get rid of it?

Comment: Looks like you have constants with these margins setup in the storyboard. So it behaves exactly as it should.

Comment: Those margins are the green ones.. He doesn't want the padding inside the label itself.

Answer (score 5):

you have to be beware of "**Constrain to margins:**"

compare these two images:
[image: Constrain to margins = YES]
and 
[image: Constrain to marings = NO]

so unselecting "constrian to margins" while adding new constraints, should solve your padding/margin problem :-)

If you like, you can visualize these margins with "Editor/Canvas/Show Layout Rectangles"
The View without the layout rectangles:
[image: Show Layout rectangles = NO]
and layout rectangles set to show (which illustrates your problem quite good)
[image: Show Layout rectangles = YES]

Comment: Sadly I've tried this.  What I've seen is that the padding is not deterministic.  Sometimes it's higher than others... although it looks like if there's more text, the padding gets bigger.

Comment: Mh... maybe your constraints are under-determining the layout (not sure why, but maybe). To check this just type `po [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]` when paused in the debugger.

Or on the other hand, maybe try to set the label's `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`. This is important because it's the width at which the label will stop growing horizontally and start growing vertically. @Eric

Answer (score 0):

You can add horizontal center to UILabel. Then set "Greater Than or Equal" to relation of "top space to superview", and set bottom space in same way. Build and run, and you can see that dynamic height of UILabel is according to UILabel's content.

Answer (score -1):

The margins are due to the autolayout constraints you've set up. Set all of the margins to zero in the size inspector.

In case you're using Xcode 6 & support iOS 8, the constraints might be set to 'container margin' instead of 'container' itself. It's slightly different and setting a margin to container to zero will work for you. You can switch between them when you setting up the constraints in the storyboard by pressing 'Alt.'

Comment: Those margins are outside of the label, the question is about padding inside the label.